# Popup using javascript & div doesnot behave same in Firefox & IE

Tags: javascript, html, popup, richfaces

I have a popup using div and javascript in a jsp page which also has some richface controls.

```
<a class="pr-toolbar-link pr-icon-help" href="#"
  onclick="popupWindow('aboutPopup',true);" 
  onblur="popupWindow('aboutPopup',false);">About</a>
<div id="aboutPopup" class="popup">
  <div class="popupbody">
<p>Some Message</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click "About" the popup is displayed properly in firefox i.e. on the top of all other things, but in IE it is overlapped by other controls. Following is the CSS

```
.popup { border: solid 1px #333; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 12px; display: none; position: absolute; width:300px; z-index:1; }
.popuptitle { background: #784574; color: white; font-weight: bold; height: 15px; padding: 5px;      }
.popupbody { background: #dee5ec; padding: 5px; text-align: center; }
#aboutPopup { top: 27px; left: 110px; }
```

I tried setting z-index value to higher then all other controls but still nothing different happens.

Edit:

Firefox popup

[image: Firefox popup]

IE7 Popup

[image: IE7 Popup]

IE7 Popup

Comment: why don't you use `<rich:modelPanel>`?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? I think in some versions of IE they wont let you cover textboxes and maybe buttons with divs because of this the textboxes always show through

Comment: I have added snap. @Gavin its IE7. @Niksvp I tried but gets the similar result.

Comment: Gavin Draper is true, I often had to hide controls which were under popuped divs with javascript in old IE so that they wouldn't show on top despite correct z-index ... This is part of old IE behaviour, nothing to do about it sadly ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the placement of the code to add the popup. I was adding the code close to the like i.e. before the menu control. So even after changing the z-index it was not in front of menu control in IE7. I just moved the code to the end after the menu control code and it worked in IE7 as well. Anyway thanks guys for suggestions.